# a patern with preg_match_all() to clean a lot of text

Tags: php, regex

I've googled a lot for a pattern to clean a `div` that I grab from a link.

I used this code:

```
foreach ( $html->find('.layout-post-left') as $element ) {

}
```

to grab a div, but the `div` is very long and has a lot of data.
All I need to grab are two links from this div, and they are not between a `href` tag they are within a JavaScript tag.

Can someone give me a pattern to use it with `preg_match_all()` to clean all that mess and keep the `http` address

Comment: Please show a shortened sample of the data.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>if(typeof(jQuery)=="function"){(function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};jwplayer('jwplayer-1').setup({"aspectratio":"16:9","width":"100%","primary":"flash","file":"http://dl-soccer.one2up.com/28-12-2013/mancity1p2.flv"}); </script></p> <p><div class='jwplayer' id='jwplayer-2'></div><script type='text/javascript'>if(typeof(jQuery)=="function"){(function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};jwplayer('jwplayer-2').setup({"aspectratio":"16:9","width":"100%","primary":"flash","file":"http://dl-soccer.one2up.com/28-12-2013/mancity2.flv"}); </script>

Comment: @user3149609, please dont post long codes in the comments, feel free to edit your question, or just put a link to your code on pastebin.com for example... That way, your code is more readable and help will come faster :)

Comment: sorry mr Enissay , i wasnt know that , forgive me i'm new here ,next time i will do as u mentioned,thanks Sir

Comment: @user3149609 why not do it this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided there is no other link and that the links are absolute and HTTP (ie. they start with a `http://`) *and* they are in a JS string, then all you need is:

```
$out_array = [];
preg_match_all( "#(['\"])(http://.*?)\\1#", $element_content_string, $out_array );
var_dump($out_array);
```

The first link will be in `$out_array[2][0]`, the second in `$out_array[2][1]`.

That assumes $element_content_string is something like:

```
$element_content_string = "<script>
  var foo = 'http://foo.bar/bax?cz';
  var bar = \"http://bax:30\";
</script>";
```

EDIT: Judging by your example, my assumption about links starting with http doesnt apply. Therefore:

```
preg_match_all( "#\"file\":\\s*(['\"])(http://.*?)\\1#", $element_content_string, $out_array );
```

Comment: thanks mr himdel alot the first patern work just as i need ,,but i used  $out_array[0][3] to grab out the links i need ,,thanks a lot Sir Regards